# NSMutableRLEArray objectAtIndex:effectiveRange:: Out of bounds in populating UITableView

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am using the following code in my application.

```
NSIndexPath* ipath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[sectionInfo numberOfObjects]-1 inSection:section];
NSLog(@"ipath %@",ipath);
[self.myTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:ipath atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
```

And getting the log like this

**ipath  {length = 2, path = 1 - 9}**

But the application crashes with getting the error like

***Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: 'NSMutableRLEArray objectAtIndex:effectiveRange:: Out of bounds'***

but if I run the project after commenting like

```
//[self.myTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:ipath atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
```

it works fine.I am using fetchedresultcontroller for populating table view and object at indexpath is not null.Any help will be appreciable?

Answer (score 3):

Use this code it may help you

```
  UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[yourTableName cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  [yourTableName setContentOffset:CGPointMake(cell.frame.origin.x, cell.frame.origin.y) animated:NO];
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.It's not crashing.But it is not scrolling to the indexpath

Comment: it will set contentOffset of you tableView for your current cell.

Comment: I am usnig custom cells.When I used the above code am getting null value for 'cell'

Comment: then pls check your indexPath. I think your indexPath is not proper.